# Firebase iOS - access user object from other view controller

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two view controllers, one where the user register (email, password ) himself into the app, and an other one where he can choose a username, I manage to get the first view controller working with Firebase this means that my user is authenticated and I manage to enter his email adress into the realtime database, but I have problem updating the username he choose to the database, I tried this :

```
self.ref.child("Users").child(user.uid).setValue(["username": usernameTextfield.text])
```

I believe this is not working because my viewcontroller doesn't know the object user. Can someone tell me how to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created a `user` object in the context of your first view controller, then you're right, you won't be able to access this from the second view controller.

However you can recreate this `user` object on the second view controller by calling `Auth.auth().currentUser`, shown below:

```
if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
    // use the user object here
    self.ref.child("Users").child(user.uid).setValue(["username": usernameTextfield.text])
} else {
    print("no user is logged in")
}
```

Comment: Hi Bradley, I manage to do it on my own but this is the solution I found too. Thanks